# Knockout viewmodel function not accessible

Tags: knockout.js

This is Working now. Below is the modified version of this code.
var data = $.getJSON("URL", null, function (result) {

```
                        var notes = function () {
                            self = this;
                            self.notes = ko.observableArray(result);
                            self.deleteNote = function (note) {
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: "URL" + this.ID,
                                    dataType: "json",
                                    type: "GET",
                                    success: function (d) {
                                        self.notes.remove(note);
                                    }
                                });
                            };

                            self.addNote = function () {
                                var note = $("#txtNote").val();
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: "URL",
                                    type: "POST",
                                    data: { 'note': note },
                                    datatype: "json",
                                    success: function (data) {
                                        self.notes.push({ Description: note, ID: data.ResponseData.id, CreateDate: data.ResponseData.createDate });
                                    }
                                });
                            }


                        }
                        ko.applyBindings(new notes());
                    });
```

Thanks,
JSHunjan

Comment: This is fixed now and I have modified my question accordingly.

Comment: I am not sure how can I mark this question as fixed. Please close this question.

Answer (score 2):

This line probably is the issue

```
viewModel.notes.remove(this);
```

`this` points to the current function, so the remove function doesn't know what to remove.

If you are using `click` binding, which I assume you do, the actual note will be passed to the function, and this then should be your solution (untested). I added the `note` variable

```
   removePerson: function (note) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "URL",
            type: "POST",
            success: function () {
                viewModel.notes.remove(note);
            }
        })
    }
```

Read the doc here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I tried this but no luck. Here is the error I am receiving in firefox.

Error: Unable to parse bindings. Message: ReferenceError: removePerson is not defined; Bindings value: click: removePerson

Comment: @JSHunjan you are probably using it in an element inside `foreach: notes` binding body. Current context will be a `notes` element then, not your whole model. Try `click: $parent.removePerson`. Also, what's the point of using Knockout if you have to write things like `$('#txtNote').val()`? Just use `value` binding.

Comment: yeah, you'll either have to user `$parent.removePerson` or `$data.removePerson`. Not just removeperson